# What are the bus options from Sofia to Ruse (Bulgaria)?

Tags: buses, bulgaria, sofia

I'm looking for a website that shows all available coaches and their schedules from Sofia to Ruse and of course in the end I want to book the ticket. I was able to find only etapgroup.com which offers only 4 schedules, but I think there should be more. Do you know any website(s) which shows the bus lines and schedules from Sofia to Ruse(Bulgaria)?

Comment: Did you check [Rome2Rio](https://www.rome2rio.com/s/Sofia/Ruse)? It shows several.

Comment: [BusRadar](https://www.busradar.com/search/?From=Sofia&To=Ruse&When=2016-12-08&Passengers=1) shows at least 10 options every two hours or so.

Comment: Thanks I wasnt able to see Union Ivkovni, I will choose them I think!

Answer (score 2):

Compiling comments into an answer:

1. [Rome2rio](https://www.rome2rio.com/s/Sofia/Ruse)
2. [Busradar](https://www.busradar.com/search/?From=Sofia&To=Ruse&When=2016-12-08&Passengers=1)